# Ubuntu 20.04 Dell xps 13 touchpad not working after login

Tags: mouse, dell, touchpad

Trackpad stopped working, but bluetooth mouse works as usual. Happens only after login.

`xinput` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Designer Mouse                            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Designer Keyboard Consumer Control        id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and for 12 here are the props:

```
Device 'DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (302): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (303): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (304):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (305):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (306):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (307):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (308):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (309):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (310):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (311):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (312): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (313):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (314):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (315):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (316):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (293): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (294): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (298): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (299): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (275):    1739, 30383
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (301):   1
```

How can I fix/debug it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out after many days of debugging this that the touchpad setting was turned off, I have no idea why nor do I recall doing this.

[image]

Comment: It also happened to me touchpad was disable without my knowledge, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Same for me. You saved my day! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My touchpad would not work, but my touchscreen luckily still worked. I went in the settings as you did and my touchpad setting was still enabled. I toggled it off and then back on.

Following the advice of touchpad issues from 18.04, I ran the following commands:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and
`sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

After these commands and a reboot, my touchpad was working again.